# VS Code JavaScript debug terminal has malware. How to remove it?

Tags: security, malware, javascript-debugger

I just started experimenting with the .NET framework and I noticed that when I run:

`dotnet list package`in the JavaScript Debug Terminal of VS Code I get all my packages as I should but they have strange Links attached to some of them that lead to scam sites.

ex:
`> Windows.EntityFrameworkCore.SQlite` --> ww1 .entityframework.com which is a shitty site pretending to be .NET hiring developers.
....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSUO0.jpg)

I tried running anti virus scans and cleanups. Nothing detected.

I tested on PowerShell, GitBash and Cmd terminals. Nothing, only happens in the JavaScript Debug Terminal

I tried disabling all my VS Code extensions (including the built-in ones) except the JavaScript debugger to see if its coming form another extension. Still there.

I have heard of extension vulnerabilities and VS Code Hacks but this is a built-in plugin.

Has this happened to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode is configured to attempt to parse strings from any output that could represent a valid URL and present the option to you as a clickable link for convenience.

Since `.tools` is a valid TLD, it thinks the string `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is referencing the URL `http://microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/` which it seems has been parked by an unscrupulous individual or organization. You as the developer should understand that this is a namespace reference and not a URL, and thus there is no value in clicking it.

This is not indicative of any sort of malware or any real malfeasance.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and enlightening answer.